# how to use background-size with point values in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I am using this CSS background image to display a tiling pattern on my DIV.

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 20px), repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 20px);
```

In the background a framework is used (react-grid-layout) that maps these tiles accordingly. Based on the values in the React Grid Layout I calculate the mapped tiles (length and width) and the result is a point value. This length and width I use with background-size to display the correct tile size visually.

```
background-size: 12.4016px 12px;
```

With Google Chrome, this is not a problem and results in the right representation of the underlying grid. Under Firefox, the tiles are distorted. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: tiles are not distorted but badly drawn, somehow FF is rounding unevenly the repeated gradient at screen. increase the original size of the gradient should help but will be not as sharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a value slightly bigger than `1px`

```css
html {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(  0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 1.3px, transparent 0), 
    linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 1.3px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 12.4016px 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach than @termaniAfif

You may increase your repeating gradient size, so FF still has something to show after *(mysterious ;) )* render calculation is made via background-size.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: 
      repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 30px), 
      repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 30px);
  background-size: 12.4016px 12px;
}
```

```html
repeating-gradient increased from 20px to 30px
```